# Batch Launches exe with arguments

Tags: batch-file, arguments, exe, launch

I'm trying to convert this line into Batch how would one start this exe with the arguments!?

```
Run("""C:\Program Files\Pro Inc\v420\commonfiles\TCL\bin\intel\cron.exe""  ""C:\Program Files\Pro Inc\v420\CommonFiles\Launcher\dank.thc"" -runae")
```

how does one do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be the problem? This should do, I guess (if you are talking about Windows batch files):

```
"C:\Program Files\Pro Inc\v420\commonfiles\TCL\bin\intel\cron.exe" "C:\Program Files\Pro Inc\v420\CommonFiles\Launcher\dank.thc" -runae
```

That is, just specify the name of the executable to invoke, including the path if necessary (enclosed in double quotes if the name and/or the path contain spaces and/or other special characters), followed by a list of arguments. An argument may need to be quoted too if there's a chance it would be misinterpreted as several arguments otherwise (or, likewise, if it contains characters with special meaning).

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on monday I don't have the file at home its at work. I kept getting an error of some type.

Also it would be 

`START "C:\Program Files\Pro Inc\v420\commonfiles\TCL\bin\intel\cron.exe" "C:\Program Files\Pro Inc\v420\CommonFiles\Launcher\dank.thc" -runae`

correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use `START` if you want to make sure the batch file *doesn't* wait for the program to finish before going on. But if you do end up using `START`, add an empty pair of double quotes just before the program's full path, like this: `START "" "C:ProgramFiles\Pro Inc\...`. It's needed because the first quoted argument of `START` is treated as the title of the window. (Just another quirk of batch scripting.)